# Angular Ivy i18n: No translation found for <ID>

Tags: angular, internationalization

I've updated an existing Angular application that uses i18n to version 9. After doing this, it throws errors during build that it cannot find my translations:

```
No translation found for "6570363013146073520" ("Dashboard")
```

I noted that the ID provided above does not exist in my `messages.xlf` files and looks to be in a totally different format.

Here's what it looked like before Angular 9:

```
<trans-unit id="f65253954b66e929a8b4d5ecaf61f9129f8cec64" datatype="html">
  <source>Dashboard</source>
  <target state="final">The translated string</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I [found this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34056) on Github that talks about the problem, but I don't understand how it's fixed. How do I tell Angular to use the "legacy format" that they are talking about in that issue?

Or is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I found a way to pass the error, you need to give id like this :

```
<h1 i18n="@@anyId">
  I don&apos;t output any element
</h1>
```

instead of `i18n="ba0cc104d3d69bf669f97b8d96a4c5d8d9559aa3"`, then in your `.xlf` file you need to use like this:

```
<trans-unit id="anyId" datatype="html">
   <source>I don&apos;t output any element</source>
   <target>Je n'affiche aucun élément</target>
   <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">app\app.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">10</context>
   </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

well by this, error will be vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you create a translation file with errors. Make sure it has the correct tag for translation content. You need only to add a new tag with translation content `<target></target>` after original content in tag `<source></source>`. For example:

```
<trans-unit id="ba0cc104d3d69bf669f97b8d96a4c5d8d9559aa3" datatype="html">
   <source>I don&apos;t output any element</source>
   <target>Je n'affiche aucun élément</target>
   <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">app\app.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">10</context>
   </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```